# Object of class DateTime could not be converted

Tags: php, datetime

I can see that there are many questions along these lines but I am very confused as to why the following does not work, taken straight from the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$tempDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');
echo $tempDate;
```

The error:

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string.

In fact every example in the docs gives me this error. Any ideas?

Comment: `$tempDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');
echo date_format($tempDate, 'Y-m-d');
`
Or you can use `echo date("d.m.Y", strtotime($somedate))`  after setting  `$somedate = @new DateTime();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't `echo` the `DateTime` object directly. You have to use the [`format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method to get the date and / or time part:

```
$tempDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');
echo $tempDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// NOT echo $tempDate!!!
```

> **demo:** http://ideone.com/IyqRWj

If you want to see the details of the object (for debug) you can use [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php):

```
$tempDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');
var_dump($tempDate);
```

Comment: Thanks but I get the error even if I remove the echo. It is the DateTime::createFromFormat where the error occurs.

Comment: @RGriffiths `DateTime::createFromFormat()` does not produce such an error message. It returns `NULL` when it cannot create a `DateTime` object and it doesn't attempt to use it as string anyway. The error message is clearly generated by code that runs **after** `DateTime::createFromFormat()` returns the `DateTime` object it creates.

Comment: @RGriffiths - no the error is on the echo! See the demo.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am slightly embarrassed to admit that the error was from a separate page being tested inadvertently but all working now.

Answer (score 1):

The error message:

> PHP Catchable fatal error: Object of class `DateTime` could not be converted to string.

is self-explanatory. The statement:

```
echo $tempDate;
```

attempts to print a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) object. The [`echo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) language construct expects a string, you pass it a `DateTime` object. The `DateTime` class does not implement the [`__toString()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) [magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) and PHP doesn't know how to convert a `DateTime` object to string.

There are so many ways to represent a `DateTime` object as string and all of them are handled by the [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method.

---

> In fact every example in the docs gives me this error.

In fact, [**every** example](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#refsect1-datetime.createfromformat-examples) in the documentation of `DateTime::createFromFormat()` reads:

```
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

which is a different thing that `echo $date;`.

---

> Any ideas?

Read the documentation of [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) carefully.